# unable to render listView item in expanded panel list flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

please is there a way i can make a list items in an expanded panel scrollable.
i tried to achieved that in the bellow code but i am getting bottom overflow error when i expand the first panel . thanks

```
 ExpansionPanelList(
              children: [
                ExpansionPanel(
                  isExpanded: _isOpen[0],
                  headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
                    return Text("Activities");
                  },
                  body: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        _myListView(),
                        // _myListView(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ExpansionPanel(
                  isExpanded: _isOpen[1],
                  headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
                    return Text("Ports");
                  },
                  body: Text("Test!!!"),
                )
              ],
              expansionCallback: (i, isOpen) {
                setState(() {
                  _isOpen[i] = !isOpen;
                });
              },
            )
```

here is my myListView function,

```
 Widget _myListView() {
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: List1.keys.map((String key) {
          return new CheckboxListTile(
            title: new Text(key),
            value: List1[key],
            activeColor: Colors.black,
            checkColor: Colors.white,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
              setState(() {
                List1[key] = value!;
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your column `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
               // your ExpansionPanelList
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

And also add `physics: ScrollPhysics(),` in `_myListView()` widget

```
 Widget _myListView() {
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        children: List1.keys.map((String key) {
          return new CheckboxListTile(
            title: new Text(key),
            value: List1[key],
            activeColor: Colors.black,
            checkColor: Colors.white,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                List1[key] = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for always being there. This worked for me. Please is there a way I can have a container before the singleChildScrowView? I tried it by wrapping both the container and the singlechildscrowview in a column but it doesn't work, and it stop scrolling. Thank  you

Comment: You are welcome, please create a separate question for this, I will answer there because of SO rules https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question

Comment: Alright, I will ask right away

Comment: ok i will there